# How to implement Jquery plugin as external file in angular2 project?

Tags: jquery, html, angular, jquery-plugins, angular2-routing

I have a website template that Consists from Html , JavaScript and Jquery plugins like (owl.carousel.min.js,slider.js ...)
I need to implement this files in Angular2 project.
The implementing of the jquery lib is succeed after installing it using the "npm":

`npm install jquery  --save`

and making reference to it in my app by adding this line in the angular.config file:

`"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ],`

Moreover I added the external jquery plugins files into my app by:

1. putting the plugin file in this Path "src/assets/Js/nameOfThePlugin.js"
2. Making a reference in the index.html file

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/Js/nameOfThePlugin.js"></script>`

> Note: I don't know if this is the correct way.

After That the jquery plugin work! but not in properly way, because once i switch between the pages (using angular2 routing) the plugin doesn't work unless you refresh the browser.

and This is example of what i'm talking about:

1. [Image Before switching between the website pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzzJv.png)
2. [Image After switching between the website pages looks how the jquery plugin stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofRAD.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will works well in production mode :
  ng build --prod
  or you have to import that plugin into angular.cli.json file.